# Can i make a container the size of the text inside without wrapping

Tags: html, css

The best way to describe my problem is by viewing the js-fiddle i created:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkY7p/

I would like the nested ul to become the size of the longest li inside, without the line wrapping, so it appears like:
We are long and annoying
rather then:
We are
long and 
annoying

I'm already using jquery on the page so that solution is possible, but if it is possible to do it with css, this option is preferred.

I don't think it's possible but I thought I would ask anyway

Any responses are appreciated =]

Comment: if your word didn't break it will collapse with the adjacent text look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/tkY7p/5/)

Comment: @krish - you can fix that by removing the `position : absolute` from the `ul`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `white-space` CSS property:

```
li {  white-space: nowrap; }
```

[jsfiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/tkY7p/8/)

Comment: I didn't know about that css property, that's exactly what I was after thankyou.